# Hardening Apache authentication to block brute force attacks

Tags: apache, security, denial-of-service

Is there a way to configure Apache to slow down login after failed attempts?

It looks like it is not the default setting as already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806549/does-apache-basic-authentication-defend-brute-force-attacks).

On the other side it seems to be possible also without adding it to own application logic, on plain Apache, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522531/why-http-authentication-with-htaccess-get-slow-when-password-incorrect), but I found nothing in documentation and discussion???

Thanks
   Achim

Comment: Doesn't seem like a programming question. Better on ServerFault, perhaps.

Comment: Aaah, good hint, thanks helping a newbie :-)

Comment: Server Fault: [Hardening Apache authentication to block brute force attacks (e.g. delay)](https://serverfault.com/questions/370445/hardening-apache-authentication-to-block-brute-force-attacks-e-g-delay) asked 2012-03-16